# Error: How to fix import demo for wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, importerror

while i import demo in wordpress theme, i got the following

"Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\random\framework\includes\wpalchemy\MetaBox.php on line 545" error.

When the line of the shortcut to go to the

"// try to fix corrupted serialized data, specifically "\r\n" being converted to "\n" during wordpress XML export (WXR)
// "maybe_unserialize()" fixes a wordpress bug which double serializes already serialized data during export/import $value = maybe_unserialize( preg_replace( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!es', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", stripslashes( $meta['value'] ) ) );

```
                        update_post_meta( $post_id, $key,  $value );"
```

was already written.

What to do to be corrected in this case. if there is no problem in staying the error, it will not do anything because it works theme. This was my first message so I will always remember the person who answered. thank you. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of PHP Deprecated function usage.

```
 maybe_unserialize( preg_replace( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!es', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", stripslashes( $meta['value'] ) ) )
```

Replace with below code:

```
preg_replace_callback( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!s', array( $this, 'fix_serialized_string_type_callback' ), stripslashes( $meta['value'] ) );
```

And add below function in same file (wp-content\themes\random\framework\includes\wpalchemy\MetaBox.php),

```
protected function fix_serialized_string_type_callback( $matches ) {
        return sprintf( 's:%s:"%s";', strlen( $matches[2] ), $matches[2] );
    }
```

If this is not work upgrade your framework. I think framework author fixed this issue

https://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy/blob/master/wp-content/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php

Comment: Thank you that part okay, I did what you said. now I've received other errors in the metabox.php directory site does not open at all. For instance

static function _is_post ()
static function _is_page()
static function _is_post_or_page()
static function _get_current_post_type()
...

 there are a lot of faulty lines starting looking like, what should I do now?

Comment: function _import($post_id, $key, $value)
 {
  if (WPALCHEMY_MODE_ARRAY == $this->mode AND $key == $this->id)
  {
   // using $wp_import to get access to the raw postmeta data prior to it getting passed
   // through "maybe_unserialize()" in "plugins/wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php"
   // the "import_post_meta" action is called after "maybe_unserialize()"
   
   global $wp_import;
 
   foreach ( $wp_import->posts as $post )
   {

Comment: if ( $post_id == $post['post_id'] )
    {
     foreach( $post['postmeta'] as $meta )
     {
      if ( $key == $meta['key'] )
      { 
       
        
          
          
           
       // try to fix corrupted serialized data, specifically "\r\n" being converted to "\n" during wordpress XML export (WXR)
       // "maybe_unserialize()" fixes a wordpress bug which double serializes already serialized data during export/import

Comment: $value = preg_replace_callback( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!s', array( $this, 'fix_serialized_string_type_callback' ), stripslashes( $meta['value'] ) ); 
       
      update_post_meta( $post_id, $key,  $value );
 
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }


          protected function fix_serialized_string_type_callback( $matches ); }
       { return sprintf( 's:%s:"%s";', strlen( $matches[2] ), $matches[2] );
     
 }

Comment: I think you are using theme having wpalchemy framework not updated very long time. update the theme or framework.

Comment: I bought the theme new, I asked this site to try. I'm going to ask them for customer support. thanks.